# CakePHP how to get shell script to use correct database connection

Tags: php, bash, shell, cakephp, configuration

I'm using CakePHP 2.x

I'm trying to figure out how to let my shell script detect whether the environment is my local dev server or the remote. In particular, I need my script to choose the correct database connection, as well as the right base URL for links.

I solve this for the web app by choosing the database connection with a switch statement that checks `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. Of course, this is not an option for the shell script.

So my question is who to write my script in such a way that avoids the following problems:

1. Hardcoding the settings, which will cause things to break when moved between environments.
2. Passing all the dynamic settings as parameters to my shell script (`Ex: myscript -db dev -url whocares.com`)

The best option I can think of is to set up a flag (Ex: `myscript -env local`) and then have the script dynamically set the database connection, domain, etc. But this still feels awkward, and I'm hoping there's a better way that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

We are using this plugin for exactly this purpose and a few more.

https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-environments

It allows you to detect your environment or simply set it based on a system variable. Read the documentation it explains everything.

Comment: This looks great. It appears to allow the developer to pass tests to detect the environment. Can I ask what tests you guys use to determine the environment? Without `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` I'm not sure how to differentiate my local server from the remote (using PHP).

Comment: We run 4 different machines with different IPs behind a loadbalancer, so we use the IPs to detect them. But like I said, you can even set a global system var like `set CAKE_ENV=dev` (Windows) and read that from within php. Or use a hostname, a mac address, some hardware id... Whatever you want.

Comment: Ohhh so then my php logic could look for $_SERVER['CAKE_ENV']. Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.